# I want to copy non blank cell and corresponding header to another sheet in required destination

Tags: excel, vba

From below mentioned code, I need an output like in `output` tab:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim rngMyCell As Range
Dim wsInputTab As Worksheet
Dim wsOutputTab As Worksheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set wsInputTab = Sheets("Input") 'Name of input sheet. Change to suit if necessary.
Set wsOutputTab = Sheets("Output") 'Name of output sheet. Change to suit if necessary.

For Each rngMyCell In wsInputTab.Range("A3:A" & wsInputTab.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    If IsError(rngMyCell) = False Then
        If Len(rngMyCell) > 0 Then
                wsOutputTab.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rngMyCell

        End If
    End If
Next rngMyCell

Set wsInputTab = Nothing
Set wsOutputTab = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Done."

End Sub
```

Comment: What's your question? Do you get errors?

Comment: So, the header is not getting copied, is that the problem?